# Weird MFMailComposeViewController Crash

Tags: objective-c, uikit

Following lines are crashing on iPad. I am using Xcode 4.6.3 (4H1503) with 6.0 as target OS platform. It used to work just fine!

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

With following exceptions:

> 2013-09-04 02:30:47.489 MyProject[38633:5b0b] *** Assertion failure in
>   NSDictionary *_UIRecordArgumentOfInvocationAtIndex(NSInvocation *,
>   NSUInteger, BOOL)(),
>   /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UIAppearance.m:1118
>
> 2013-09-04 02:31:00.816 MyProject[38633:5b0b] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Unknown key, "{size = 13.000000, traits =
>   00000000}" in title text attributes dictionary'

EDIT: Its crashing due to the following lines. Any guess why? Never thought `MFMailComposeViewController` could have any relation to `UITabBarItem` ...

```
NSDictionary *textAttributesDict = @{ [UIColor whiteColor] : UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                          [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f] : UITextAttributeFont};

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributesDict forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributesDict forState:UIControlStateNormal]`;
```

Comment: Have you checked that the device can send mail? Does your compose view have a delegate?

Comment: The exception mentions UIAppearance. Have you customized the appearance of any controls that may be used by the compose view? (navigation bars for example)? If so, how?

Comment: Yes checking if device can send email. Not changing navigation bar appearance in anyway either.

Comment: +1 David Rönnqvist: Fixed. Updated my question, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: You might want to show `textAttributesDict` as well. Seems like something's wrong with it.

Comment: You keys and objects should be the other way around. Like this `@{key: object, ...}`

Comment: +1 Desdenova: haha, got it. Did not notice that, thanks man.

Comment: No problem, happens all the time since the initializer is other way around `initWithObjectsAndKeys:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSDictionary` had key/value reversed. It is supposed to have *key:value* instead of *value:key*

```
NSDictionary *textAttributesDict = @{ [UIColor whiteColor] : UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                          [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f] : UITextAttributeFont};
```

Changing above to the following worked. Thanks Desdenova for a pointer.

```
NSDictionary *textAttributesDict = @{UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor],
                                          UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f]};
```